# How to make this code overview tab appear on your screen ( Visual Studio )

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know how to make this tab appear on your screen? (It's an overall view of the code). I saw someone use it somewhere and took my attention:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the vertical scroll bar in so-called "Map Mode". To select this, issue the "Options" command from the "Tools" menu and navigate, in the tree in the left-hand pane, to the "Text Editor" ... "All Languages" ... "Scroll Bars" node and then, in the right-hand pane, select the "Use map mode for vertical scroll bar" radio-button:

[image]

Alternatively, you can go directly to that options page by right-clicking in the vertical scroll  bar and selecting the "Scroll Bar Options..." command.